# Flatpickr instance not allowing enableTime to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

I have been running into problems with my datepickr. I created a flatpickr instance that enables time. When I go to click on the input the datepickr calendar popups up but it is missing time. When I click off the input then click back on the time then shows up. Did I do something wrong, here is my code:

```
var dateTimeInit = function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var hour = null;
    var minute = null;
    if ($this.parent().hasClass('currentTime')) {
        var date = new Date();
        hour = date.getHours();
        minute = date.getMinutes();
    }
    $this.addClass('flatpickrInit');
    $this.attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    $this.flatpickr({
        allowInput:true,
        enableTime:true,
        dateFormat:"m/d/Y h:i K",
        defaultHour:hour,
        defaultMinute:minute,
        onReady:function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            instance.open();
        },
        onOpen:function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            var readonly = $(instance.element).attr('readonly');
            if (typeof readonly !== typeof undefined && readonly !== false) {
                instance.close();
            }
        },
        onValueUpdate:function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            $(instance.element).attr("value", $(instance.element).val());
            $(instance.element).trigger("change");
        }
    });
};
$(document).on('focusin', '.type-datetime:not(.flatpickrInit)', dateTimeInit);
```